# Why asterisk listens on port 50360?

Tags: security, asterisk

When I run: `netstat -tulpn  | grep asterisk`

I see the  following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12337/asterisk
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12337/asterisk    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50360          0.0.0.0:*                           12337/asterisk
```

I already did a google search on it and cannot seem to find why it listens on that port.

Also I searched for 50360 on all the files inside `/etc/asterisk` with

```
grep -rnw '/etc/asterisk/' -e '50360'
```

and still no luck

Comment: Does it change when you restart the process?

Comment: This port number (50360) does not seem to appear in the software sources either.

Comment: I got tired of searching I uninstalled asterisk and installed it again and now it does not listens on that port. It is so strange.

Answer (score 1):

It is res_pjsip.so.
Listen on random udp port from 30000 to 60000.
Both ipv4 and ipv6.
Different ports.
Nobody knows how to set it up.  You need to look in the source code.  Someone thinks that this is a dns client.